# Sum with group by in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a table countries_percent like following:

| country_name | group_name | percent_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | EMEA | 10.00 |
| US |  | 25.00 |
| GB | EMEA | 15.00 |
| AP | Domestic | 20.00 |
| AK | Domestic | 12.00 |
| ES |  | 5.00 |

Now I would like to select the highest sum of percent_value for each group by country e.g:

| country_name | group_name | sum_percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | EMEA | 35.00 |
| AP | Domestic | 20.00 |

so here US is selected because the sum of its percentage was highest for EMEA group. Please note that NULL group_name is counted towards EMEA because of country_name match. Also note that ES didn't appear as it didn't have any group_name against it and there is no other group with value ES.

Is it possible to query the above with Postgres?

Comment: does the solution below work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Result you bSkip Spain, because it has no group.

So you can do it like this

> ```
> WITH SUMCTE AS (SELECT "country_name", MAX("group_name") as group_name, SUM("percent_value") AS percent_value
> FROM tab1
> GROUP BY "country_name"),
> CTE_ROW_NUM AS (
> SELECT *,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "group_name" ORDER BY "percent_value" DESC ) rn 
> FROM SUMCTE
> WHERE "group_name" IS NOT NULL)
> SELECT "country_name", "group_name", "percent_value"
> FROM CTE_ROW_NUM
> WHERE rn = 1
> ORDER BY  "percent_value" DESC
> ```

> ```
> country_name | group_name | percent_value
> :----------- | :--------- | ------------:
> US           | EMEA       |         35.00
> AP           | Domestic   |         20.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f95dfc43635048e02c3f24cd20b6644c)*

Answer (score 0):

[SAMPLE DATA RESULTS](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a4cd7e64528145b136e81ca2f6e3c8fc)

```
    WITH country_level_info AS (
        SELECT
          country_name,
          MAX(group_name) AS group_name, -- MAXIMUM ON GROUP NAME WILL CHOOSE THE NON NULL VALUE WHICH IS WHAT WE WANT
          SUM(percent_value) AS sum_percent
        FROM data 
        GROUP BY 1 
        HAVING MAX(group_name) != '' OR  MAX(group_name) != NULL
        ),
        ranking AS (
        SELECT  
          *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY sum_percent DESC) AS rank_
        FROM country_level_info
        )
        SELECT country_name, 
               group_name, 
               sum_percent 
        FROM ranking WHERE rank_ = 1
        ORDER BY sum_percent DESC
```